# How to get an array(say arrayGroupBy) of dictionary from array of dictionary, where some key’s value are matching in another dictionary key’s value

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, nsarray, nsdictionary

i have an NSMutable arrray containing NSDictionaries like this:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x7a2b4b00>(
{
"appointment_id" = 235;
"component_name" = Anil;
id = 5;
"start_time" = "2014-11-04 19:00:00";
"time_slot" = "7:00 PM";
},
{
    "appointment_id" = 235;
"component_name" = "test_book";
id = 19;
"start_time" = "2014-11-04 19:00:00";
"time_slot" = "7:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 235;
"component_name" = "New Resource";
id = 21;
"start_time" = "2014-11-04 19:00:00";
"time_slot" = "7:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 236;
"component_name" = ctbl;
id = 8;
"start_time" = "2014-11-04 22:00:00";
"time_slot" = "10:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 236;
"component_name" = btbl;
id = 7;
"start_time" = "2014-11-04 22:00:00";
"time_slot" = "10:00 PM";
  },
{
"appointment_id" = 236;
    "component_name" = "New Resource";
id = 21;
"start_time" = "2014-11-04 22:00:00";
"time_slot" = "10:00 PM";
}
)
```

how do i create a new array say arrGroupByTimeSlots from above structure some thing like this:

```
array of time slot
(
time_slot = (an array of dictionaries with matching time_slot)
time_slot = (an array of dictionaries with matching another time_slot)
)
```

in detail:

```
(
time_slot = ({
"appointment_id" = 235;
"component_name" = Anil;
id = 5;
"start_time" = "2014-11-04 19:00:00";
"time_slot" = "7:00 PM";
}, {
"appointment_id" = 235;
"component_name" = "test_book";
id = 19;
"start_time" = "2014-11-04 19:00:00";
"time_slot" = "7:00 PM";
}, {
"appointment_id" = 235;
"component_name" = "New Resource";
id = 21;
"start_time" = "2014-11-04 19:00:00";
"time_slot" = "7:00 PM";
}),

time_slot = ({
"appointment_id" = 236;
"component_name" = ctbl;
id = 8;
"start_time" = "2014-11-04 22:00:00";
"time_slot" = "10:00 PM";
}, {
"appointment_id" = 236;
"component_name" = btbl;
id = 7;
"start_time" = "2014-11-04 22:00:00";
"time_slot" = "10:00 PM";
}, {
"appointment_id" = 236;
"component_name" = "New Resource";
id = 21;
"start_time" = "2014-11-04 22:00:00";
"time_slot" = "10:00 PM";
}))
```

what i have tried: solution provided by **Onik IV** as it is.

***some more log:pay attention to "time_slot" = "7:00 PM";***
the array of dictionaries i want to sort :

```
Printing description of arrAllocated:
<__NSArrayM 0x19055f70>(
{
"appointment_id" = 244;
"component_name" = "badge test";
id = 20;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 19:00:00";
"time_slot" = "7:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 246;
"component_name" = p1;
id = 42;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 18:00:00";
"time_slot" = "6:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 246;
"component_name" = p2;
id = 41;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 18:00:00";
"time_slot" = "6:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 246;
"component_name" = p3;
id = 43;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 18:00:00";
"time_slot" = "6:00 PM";
}, 
{
"appointment_id" = 247;
"component_name" = p4;
id = 44;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 19:00:00";
"time_slot" = "7:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 247;
"component_name" = p5;
id = 45;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 19:00:00";
"time_slot" = "7:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r1;
id = 29;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r10;
id = 38;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r11;
id = 39;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r12;
id = 40;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r2;
id = 30;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r3;
id = 31;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r4;
id = 32;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r5;
id = 33;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r6;
id = 34;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r7;
id = 35;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r8;
id = 36;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r9;
id = 37;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
}
)
```

after sorting using **Onik IV** method this is what i am getting pay attention to "time_slot" = "7:00 PM";:

```
<__NSArrayM 0x17e9b660>(
<__NSArrayM 0x19088e80>(
{
"appointment_id" = 244;
"component_name" = "badge test";
id = 20;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 19:00:00";
"time_slot" = "7:00 PM";
}
)
,
<__NSArrayM 0x190543b0>(
{
"appointment_id" = 246;
"component_name" = p1;
id = 42;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 18:00:00";
"time_slot" = "6:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 246;
"component_name" = p2;
id = 41;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 18:00:00";
"time_slot" = "6:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 246;
"component_name" = p3;
id = 43;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 18:00:00";
"time_slot" = "6:00 PM";
}
)
,
<__NSArrayM 0x1905d750>
(
{
"appointment_id" = 247;
"component_name" = p4;
id = 44;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 19:00:00";
"time_slot" = "7:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 247;
"component_name" = p5;
id = 45;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 19:00:00";
"time_slot" = "7:00 PM";
}
)
,
<__NSArrayM 0x190243e0>
(
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r1;
id = 29;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r10;
id = 38;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r11;
id = 39;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r12;
id = 40;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r2;
id = 30;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r3;
id = 31;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r4;
id = 32;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r5;
id = 33;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r6;
id = 34;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r7;
id = 35;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r8;
id = 36;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
},
{
"appointment_id" = 245;
"component_name" = r9;
id = 37;
"start_time" = "2014-11-11 17:00:00";
"time_slot" = "5:00 PM";
```

}
)

)

if you see ***"time_slot" = "7:00 PM";***

it is not grouped in the same array where other "time_slot" = "7:00 PM"; are grouped.

hope i am able to make it more clear.
thanks and regards.

Comment: Have you try something?

Comment: yes i have tried it using predicates see edit

Comment: Does it have to be dictionaries? Can't you use custom objects instead?

Comment: Also, what if there are two time slots of the same time (7PM) but on a different date? Are they counted as being the same?

Comment: @Fogmeister thanks for the answer, yes for the time being as per project requirements(we dont managing data model for this scenarion), i have to sort this dictionary.

Comment: @Fogmeister just the key to pay attention is "time_slot", apart from "start_time"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
NSArray *arrAllocated; // Your initial array
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"time_slot" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sorts = @[sort];
NSArray *orderedArrAllocated = [arrAllocated sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sorts];

NSMutableArray *groupedFilterArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *currentMutableArray;
NSDictionary *lastObject;

for (NSDictionary *dict in orderedArrAllocated)
{
    if ([[dict valueForKey:@"time_slot"] isEqualToString:[lastObject valueForKey:@"time_slot"]])
    {
        [currentMutableArray addObject:dict];
    }
    else
    {
        NSMutableArray *newMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:dict, nil];
        lastObject = dict;
        currentMutableArray = newMutableArray;
        [groupedFilterArray addObject:newMutableArray];

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, its grouping some of the dictionaries but not others

Comment: @Alok please explain what is not working here. When you say it is not grouping others. What exactly do you mean? Which others? I was about to write an answer and realised that it's exactly the same as this.

Comment: @Fogmeister let me debug and provide you the log

Comment: @Alok you haven't implemented this solution properly. Specifically you haven't **sorted** the array at the beginning. The first 4 lines of this solution sort the array in order of the time slots. This has to be done so that similar time slots are next to each other.

Comment: OMG let me check i have intentionally removed this, so that my order of objects in array did not change..:(

Comment: @Alok note that you're not changing the order of the initial array. You are creating a **new array** that is sorted. The initial array is untouched by this method.

Comment: @Fogmeister thank you very much for awsome support, onik  thank you very much, your answer was right at very first point.

Comment: @Fogmeister thank you, I was out I didm´t see this question until now. Thanks you.

Comment: @OnikIV no worries. I was about to write an answer and realised it was identical to this :D I think it might be possible with predicates and stuff but this is the simplest. Quick too, only one pass of the array.

Answer (score 3):

I use something like this:

```
NSArray *yourArray = /* Initialize */;
// Get all time slots
NSArray *allTimeSlotsArray = [yourArray valueForKey:@"time_slot"];
// Remove duplucates
NSSet *allTimeSlotsSet = [NSSet setWithArray:allTimeSlotsArray];
  // Enumerate
NSMutableDictionary *recordsByTimeSlot = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString *timeSlot in allTimeSlotsSet) {
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"time_slot == %@", timeSlot];
  NSArray *matchingArray = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
  recordsByTimeSlot[timeSlot] = matchingArray;
}
```

**UPDATED:**
<s>Store `matchingArray` or do whatever you need.</s>
Use the resulting `recordsByTimeSlot` dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

@orkenstein answer works perfectly here. But the only issue is if you dont save the matching array it will be overwritten. For that you can use an NSMutableArray and add the matching array inside the for loop. I dont have enough reputation to post this as a comment, so I'm posting it as an answer. :)

```
-(void)filteredArray
{
      NSArray *yourArray = originalArray;
      // Get all time slots
      NSArray *allTimeSlotsArray = [yourArray valueForKey:@"time_slot"];
      // Remove duplucates
      NSSet *allTimeSlotsSet = [NSSet setWithArray:allTimeSlotsArray];
      // Enumerate
    for (NSString *timeSlot in allTimeSlotsSet) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"time_slot == %@", timeSlot];
        NSArray *matchingArray = [yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
        [finalArray addObjectsFromArray:matchingArray];
    }
    NSLog(@"Filtered Array : %@",finalArray);
}
```

finalArray is an NSMutableArray object.

Comment: I thought it's too obvious )